# how to integrate CubePoints in asgaros forum

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i used asgaros forum plugin for forum but i want to show user role by points and want to integrate Cube Points plugins with asgaros forum plugin.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using Hooks/filter creating new custom plugin and store points in newly created table and integrate with forum plugin.show user on the basis of point.